# Monotuch : Array RootElement

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

How to can i define array with RootElement Type?
My pseudo code is:

```
RootElement LanguageElement = array();

LanguageElement[1] = some codes;
LanguageElement[2] = some another codes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no different than any other object array in C#

```
RootElement[] root = new RootElement[10];

root [0] = new RootElement ("caption 1");
...
root [9] = new RootElement ("caption 10");
```